# Separate group results for periods of time

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, date

I own several results on my `table` and it there is a `date` column that is in `timestamp` format.

Playing this code `SELECT * FROM table group by date` he gathers in groups of EQUAL dates (according to my test)

I need to organize the results into groups, where dates between them having up to 23 hours of difference

for example, this rows

- 2015-01-01 19:33:42
- 2015-01-01 19:25:42
- 2015-01-01 19:00:42
- 2015-02-01 13:25:42
- 2015-02-01 15:25:42
- 2015-03-01 16:25:42

he would have to return

- The rows of 2015-01-01 of (19:00:42 - 19:22:42)
- The rows of 2015-02-01 of (13:25:42 - 15:25:42)
- The rows of 2015-03-01 of (16:25:42 - 16:25:42)

An example of this would be operating facebook how their messages organized according to the time

[image: facebook]

How make it with PHP and MYSQL?

Answer (score 2):

Loop through them. Store the time of the last message you saw. When you come to the next you check if it is more than 24 hours. If it is you print the header. Then update last message time.